# converting curl into requests or urllib

Tags: python, ios

I am using Vis Studio Code and python3 (On IOs)

In terminal if I type the following command:

```
curl --data "method=getmydata" https://mywebsite.com/api
```

when I substitute the method for a relevant one and the website for the relevant website, it returns all the data I'm looking for.

However, I want to write a python script  which will do this (in visual studio code) and write the output json to a file I can then interrogate.

How do I do the this using urllib or requests instead?

Comment: Try using this [cURL to Requests](https://curl.trillworks.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code using `requests` package

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

```
import json
import requests
data = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
data = json.dumps(data)
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

r = requests.post("https://mywebsite.com/api", data=data, headers=headers)
print(r.text)   # or r.json() if response is json
```

If your api accepts form data then don't pass `Content-Type` header and also, no need to dumps your data. It will be

```
import requests
data = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.post("https://mywebsite.com/api", data=data)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, Appreciate your assistance.  your second solution worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [urllib.request](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request), working example:

```
def run_webRequest(url):
    import urllib.request
    opener = urllib.request.FancyURLopener({})   
    with opener.open(url) as f:
        print(f.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

You can then istead of reading, write `f` to a file and read it afterwards. Hope it helps.